# Laravel extended relationships

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I'm working on a laravel project which has multiple language versions. (or at least should have)

I have (for ex.) a Page model and a PageTranslation model. Each instance of a PageTranslation model is a single language mutation.

There are two relationships defined in the Page model. **currentTranslation** and **firstTranslation**. If there is not a translation for the page in a current language (**currentTranslation** gets part form an url), the **firstTranslation** is used.

To the problem. In view I have to write a condition like:

```
if($page->currentTranslation) {
    $pageTranslation = $page->currentTranslation;    
} else {
    $pageTranslation = $page->firstTranslation;
}
```

and than use it. It gets really annoying to write this. I'd like to have a relation called **translation** which would decide whether to use **currentTranslation** or **firstTransation** relationship.
I would do a simple query inside of that relation but, at that point, the page_id is not available.

Can you show me a solution?

And my second question is: If the above mentioned problem is solvable, would it be possible somehow to pass data from `$page->translation` to the `$page`, so I didn't have to write `$page->translation->title` but instead just `$page->title` (and it would return an title of the page in currently used language).

The Page Model

```
class Page extends Eloquent {

public function firstTranslation() {
    return $this->hasOne('PageTranslation', 'page_id', 'id')->orderBy('language_id', 'asc');
}

public function currentTranslation() {
    return $this->hasOne('PageTranslation', 'page_id', 'id')->where('language_id', '=', Config::get('app.language_id'));
}

}
```

Thank you very much!

Edit:

A friend of mine showed me this solution:

```
public function translation() {

if(Config::get('app.language_id')) {
    if($this->hasOne('PageTranslation', 'page_id', 'id')->where('language_id', '=', Config::get('app.language_id'))->first()) {
        return $this->hasOne('PageTranslation', 'page_id', 'id')->where('language_id', '=', Config::get('app.language_id'));
    }
}

return $this->hasOne('PageTranslation', 'page_id', 'id')->orderBy('language_id', 'asc');
}
```

Comment: is there any reason why you are resolving your IF inside the view instead of the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try an accessor that could be called like this:

```
// $page->translation;


class Page extends Eloquent {

  public function firstTranslation() {
    return $this->hasOne('PageTranslation', 'page_id', 'id')->orderBy('language_id', 'asc');
  }

  public function currentTranslation() {
    return $this->hasOne('PageTranslation', 'page_id', 'id')->where('language_id', '=', Config::get('app.language_id'));
  }

  public function getTranslationAttribute(){
     if($this->currentTranslation) {
        return $this->currentTranslation; 
     } else {
        return $this->firstTranslation;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It's more testable, although I'm not sure that using hasOne with where in a condition is a best practice.

Comment: Its not - I would go for a scope at that point because the hasOne and others are basically used for eager loading quickly your relationship to prevent N+1 scenario. In my opinion it would be best to SCOPE the relationship instead which enables you to chain up within the controller.

Comment: I really like your solution. Thank you very much, mister!

Answer (score 0):

After reading your friend's solution I would suggest a bit of a clean up a bit

and to use

```
class Page extends Eloquent {

public function translation($lang_id) {

if(isset($lang_id)) {
    if($this->hasOne('PageTranslation', 'page_id', 'id')->where('language_id', '=', $lang_id)->first()) {
        return $this->hasOne('PageTranslation', 'page_id', 'id')->where('language_id', '=', $land_id);
    }
}

return $this->hasOne('PageTranslation', 'page_id', 'id')->orderBy('language_id', 'asc');
}
}
```

1) it should be receiving the language_id from the outside and not from the config, it will render your model less test-able.

2) the isset is mainly as a habbit of mine to check for existance rather than rellying on null or zero.